# Finding all subtree repeats in a rooted, labeled, directed tree

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance, tree, abstract-syntax-tree

For a research project that I'm currently conducting, one of the tasks that I need to do is as follows: given a rooted, labeled, directed tree, I need to find all the *subtree repeats* within this tree; in other words, given *all* the subtrees (with at least one node) of the tree, I need to group together all the subtrees with the same sets of labels *and* same hierarchical structure. So for example, let's say we have the following tree, with root A:

```
    A
   / \
  /   \
 B     A
 |\    |\
 C C   B A
       |
       C
```

In this case, there are several repeating subtree patterns, such as the following...

Pattern 1 (occurs 3 times):

```
A
|
B
|
C
```

Pattern 2 (occurs 3 times):

```
A
|\
B A
|
C
```

Pattern 3 (occurs 2 times):

```
A
|
B
```

...and so on and so forth. FYI, the "rooted, labeled, directed tree" that I'm concerned with is an abstract syntax tree (AST) generated from JavaScript code.

Now, I've come up with my own algorithm to find all of the subtree repeats. It works well when the JavaScript code is really small (because the AST is also small), and the algorithm finishes instantly. But when I increase the number of lines of JavaScript code to only 10 lines, the algorithm doesn't even finish executing after more than an hour! **So my question is, does anyone know a more efficient and scalable algorithm to find all the subtree repeats?** FYI, the language I'm implementing this algorithm in is also JavaScript.

For your reference, my current algorithm is basically a recursive algorithm that does a post-order traversal of the tree (where post-order in this context means, "visit the children of this node first, then visit the node"). At each node visit, the algorithm finds all the subtrees rooted at that node, by going through *every combination* of subtrees of its children determined earlier in the algorithm; for each subtree it finds rooted at that node, the algorithm computes a hash value based on three things: (1) the label of the node; (2) the number of children of the node that appear *in this subtree*; and (3) the hash values of the children's subtrees that currently appear *in this subtree*. Subtrees that hash to the same value are then placed in the same group. (Potential inaccuracies with the hash functions also need to be resolved, but I haven't even gotten to that part yet...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to re-invent clone detection in abstract syntax trees.  Yes, the basic idea for matching trees is to put them into "possibly-equivalent" buckets  using hashing, and then check those that are possibly-equivalent for actual equivalence.   This is a classic compiler algorithm used to support finding common subexpressions.

If the number of equivalent subtrees is small compared to the number of hash buckets, and your hash algorithm is decent, this is essentially linear in the size of the tree.  (Bad hashing or one bucket can make this be N^2).

I didn't quite understand your algorithm; it sounds like you are basically doing that.   Without a more precise characterization (e.g., psuedocode) it will be hard to see what is wrong.

The research is long done.  See my technical paper on CloneDR, a tool that does this: http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Company/Publications/ICSM98.pdf  (You can find a JavaScript CloneDR at that same site).

There's a more difficult problem in finding subtrees which are *almost* the same, also covered by the paper.  That's by far the most interesting part,
and much harder to do fast.

We regularly run CloneDR on multi-million line systems.   At this scale, it does take hours to finish in its parallel, compiled-to-native code implementation.  JavaScript is probably not your friend for this.

Comment: I think his algorithm is much worse than linear in the size of the tree, because he considers not only the "full" subtrees rooted at each node, but also "partial" subtrees -- that is, a subtree need not contain every descendant of its root.  A Perl one-liner tells me there are 2441406 such subtrees in a height-9 complete binary tree, and 12207031 for a height-10 one.

Comment: Incidentally, I think the problem you seem to be describing (in which only "full" subtrees are considered) is probably what the OP wants to actually do...

Comment: If you try to match all possible "partial" subtrees, you get a problem similar to the one CloneDR solves in finding "near misses", that is, multiple trees that share substructure.   CloneDR is interested in such trees where the differences are small compared to the mass of the tree;  that would mean in practice a lot smaller set of partial subtrees.  But it avoids enumerating all possible partial subtrees because of the outrageous cost to do so, as you have pointed out.

Comment: @IraBaxter Thanks for your quick response! I've actually read your CloneDR paper, and in fact, that's where I got the idea for the hashing. I tried contacting you and your coauthors by email to ask how you found *all* the subtrees in the AST, but figured the email addresses may have been dead since the paper was published a while ago; so I just came up with my own algorithm to find the subtrees, and fused that with your idea of hashing into "possibly-equivalent" buckets.

Comment: @IraBaxter Just to give you some context, clone detection is *not* the primary goal of my research, but it's merely something that I've incorporated as one part of my overall design. Also, yes, I was initially looking for ways to find all subtree repeats, *including* partial subtrees, as this will provide greater accuracy wrt problem I'm working on. However, based on what you said, it seems like the lack of scalability comes mostly from looking for partial subtrees instead of just full subtrees, so I may have to refactor my design to simply employ a heuristic and consider only full subtrees.

Comment: @FrolinOcariza:  The rest of the CLoneDR paper talks about how to make it work with partial subtree matches of the small delta kind.   PS: That email address still works fine.  See my bio.